# How to make connection from Crystal Reports to Informix?

Tags: crystal-reports, informix, crystal-reports-12

I am new to Crystal Reports.  I want to make a connection to an Informix database.  Can anyone help? Connection to Oracle may also help.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to know the name of the Informix database, and the server where the database is stored, and some other related information.  You will most likely use an ODBC driver.  I'm not sure what else you need with Crystal Reports; it will have a mechanism for specifying a data source name or DSN in some shape or form.

The other related information might include the host name, server name (meaning the name of the IBM Informix Dynamic Server (IDS) itself), the port number, a username, and perhaps a password.  There are some other parameters that could be set - the exact mechanism for doing so depends on which ODBC driver you use - you might be using the Informix native ODBC driver (using SQLI protocol) or the IBM Common Client driver which uses DRDA protocol (but you need IDS configured to listen to the DRDA connections), or you might use a third-party driver - there are a few to choose from.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using an ODBC driver for Informix, and Crystal's Oracle driver for the Oracle database.